# How do I instruct spring to instantiate message listener containers?

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am using Spring 4.2.3 and Java 1.7

I have a unit test

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
public class TestJmsListener extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private JmsMessagingTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("destination")
    private Destination destination;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assert(jmsTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(destination, "test", Boolean.class));
    }

}
```

The test invokes the TestConfiguration class, but really that just extends the below configuration. In the TestConfiguration, I merely override the connectionFactory such that it instantiates an embedded activemq broker.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@ComponentScan("messaging")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:messaging.properties")
public class CommonMessagingConfiguration {

    // bunch of beans, connection factories, destinations, etc

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency("10");
        return factory;
    }

}
```

The test executes and in the logs I can see that a queue is created for my "test" message. The message is pending on the queue, however, there are no consumers of the queue. Here is my listener implementation:

```
@Component
public class JmsExampleListener {

    @JmsListener(containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory",
            destination = "${messaging.destinations.example}")
    public boolean listen(String message) {
        return message != null;
    }
}
```

When I attach a debugger to `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory#createContainerInstance()` I notice that it is ever hit. However, when I attach one to `JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#postProcessAfterInitialization` it hits that break point and I can see that spring is detecting my component. Spring instantiates it and registers that instance with it's internal registrar (as I would expect).

The problem it seems is that the containers are never created for the endpoints that are registered. I tried following the [Spring example](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-jms/blob/master/complete/src/main/java/hello/Application.java) however, they offer no insight.

One thing I noticed was that the Listener post processor has an internal registrar and that has an internal property `startImmediately` which is false. It seems that it extends the `InitializingBean` and as such, sets the start property to true which I would presume would start kicking off the containers... However, this does not happen. In fact, if I put a break point on the `afterPropertiesSet`, it is never invoked. I would assume because the instance in the post processor is not a spring managed bean.

Has anyone tried something similar to what I am doing and had the same issue?

### Update

After further investigation, it would seem as though the [`JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java) that is instantiated by the `@EnableJms` isn't having it's `afterSingletonsInstantiated` invoked after the container is configured. The logic in aforementioned method is what is responsible for constructing the `MessageListenerContainer` for all the registered endpoints. Why would the `afterSingletonsInstantiated` not get called? Shouldn't the application context automatically invoke that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I had a project dependency that was causing the spring-context sources to be version 4.0.9. After I resolved the conflict and effectively had the `AbstractApplicationContext` from 4.2.3 loaded, the components began working.